# Flexbox appears to not be honoring flex-direction: column for a header element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sure this is due to some misunderstanding on my part, but it seems like setting flex-direction: column on an element should make the children of that element show up in a horizontal row.

I'm trying to do a very simple layout.  At the top, you should see the standard logo, then some navigation links and I also have some controls.  Below that the content should be showing up with in a single column which each entry below the previous.

The content is showing up as I expect, but inside the header tag, only the links are doing what I expect.  Why is that?  What needs to be changed to make logo, link #1, link #2, a, and b all show up in a single row?

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

html {
  display: flex;
}

.App {
  flex-direction: row;
}

header {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Content {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class='App'>
  <header>
    <img src='#.png' alt='logo'>
    <nav>
      <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
      <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    </nav>
    <div class='Controls'>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class='Content'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No...`flex-direction:column` will layout elements in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving flex to the wrong element. You should give it to header because that's your parent element to all other elements in that div like this:

```
header{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
```

Check out this tutorial where they explain everything about Flexbox:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af

Or quick guide here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually removed the display: flex; entries to make the example simpler and removing them had no effect.  You have hit upon the key to my confusion.  flex-direction: row; is what I needed (along with adding display: flex;)!  Thank you so much.  I will go read the suggested links.

Answer (score 1):

`flex-direction: column` will stack element vertically, as a *column*, not horizontally, like a *row*.

As Flexbox is a parent/child relation, adding `display: flex` to the `html` will only make the `body` a flex item.

The `flex-direction` is a *flex container* property, and needs to be combined with `display: flex` (which make the element a flex container) to apply and control the children's flex direction.

In below sample, the applied properties will make the `App`'s children stack vertical, and the `header`'s horizontal.

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;          /*  stack vertically  */
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;              /*  default (can be omitted), horizontal  */
}
```

```html
<div class='App'>
  <header>
    <img src='#.png' alt='logo'>
    <nav>
      <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
      <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    </nav>
    <div class='Controls'>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class='Content'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display:flex` to the `header`.

The rest is unnecessary and the `flex-direction` statements at the moment will have no effect since you have **not** added `display:flex` to those elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='App'>
  <header>
    <img src='#.png' alt='logo'>
    <nav>
      <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
      <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    </nav>
    <div class='Controls'>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class='Content'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you're trying to use flex-direction on elements that are not flex-containers.

"Display" property is not inherited, so you're basically setting flex-direction on display:block items, which will do absolutely nothing.

You need to add display:flex to each element were you want the childrens to behave like flex-items.

```html
<style>
* {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
html {
display: flex;
}
.App {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
header {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.Content {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
</style>
<html>
    <div class='App'>
            <header>
                    <img src='#.png' alt='logo'>
                    <nav>
                            <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                            <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
                    </nav>
                    <div class='Controls'>
                            <button>a</button>
                            <button>b</button>
                    </div>
            </header>
            <div class='Content'>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: "behave like" can be reworded to "be".